# Embedded Document is not removed in case validate fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form, nested-forms

When edit product and delete a row of 'Component' model embedded in Product model, If validation is fail , the deleted document will appear in edit page again.

Update method:

```
# Put /products/:id
def update
    @product=Product.find(params[:id])

    if(@product.update_attributes(params[:product]))
        logger.info @product.attribute.components.inspect
        redirect_to product_path , notice:'update complete'
    else
        logger.info @product.attribute.components.inspect
        render_by_type_id(@product.product_type._id,false,mode='edit')

    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Product   
    include Mongoid::Document
    include ScopedSearch::Model
    embeds_one :attribute ,class_name:"ProductAttribute" 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute, :product_items ,:lab_test ,allow_destroy: true
end



class ProductAttribute  
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :product
    embeds_many :components , inverse_of: nil
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :components, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

embedded model:

```
class Component
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :product_attribute
end
```

Comment: Did you made sure that you generated the database migration for the ``_destroy`` column?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but please note that destroying through nested attributes [is executed on save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> Note that the model will *not* be destroyed until the parent is saved.

Therefore you should try if `Product.create(params[:product])` works. However, I am not sure if this works as expected and this really is what you want. The general use case for nested attribute destruction is to remove an association of an existing object. It seems strange to me to couple object creation and destruction within one param set. So if this does not answer your please try to explain what you want to achieve.